# checking gridview count after filter expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource

I'm working on an asp:GridView. On this aspx page, I'm giving users the option to search the current gridview by typing in a specific value into a textbox. Then, I set a SqlDataSource.FilterExpression based on what the user entered.

For example, user types "MODEL1" and hits search. Then:

```
SqlDataSource.FilterExpression = "ModelName= " + "'" + TextBox.Text + "'";
```

What I need to do next is check if it pulled a result or not? Obviously I can tell if it didn't on the page because there is no gridview visible. However, I need a way to catch it so I can reset the FilterExpression and throw an "Incorrect search" message at the user. I don't see any methods under FilterExpression that will help me, and I've tried GridView.Rows.Count and it doesn't seem to work. Do I have any other options or could I be doing the Rows.Count method wrong?

Here's some extra code that happens when the search event is triggered:

```
        if (TextBox.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            errorLabel.Text = "Please enter a value";
        }
        else
        {
            SqlDataSource.FilterExpression = "ModelName= " + "'" + TextBox.Text + "'";
            if (!GridView.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                errorLabel.Text = "Model not found";
                SqlDataSource.FilterExpression = "";
            }
        }
```

**EDIT:** Just wanted to add that GridView.Rows.Count produces a value of 51 which is how many rows exist without the FilterExpression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your results in a `DataView`, which has a `Count` property:

```
SqlDataSource.FilterExpression = "ModelName= " + "'" + TextBox.Text + "'";
System.Data.DataView dv = (DataView)SqlDataSource.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
dv.RowFilter = SqlDataSource.FilterExpression;
int RowCount = dv.Count;
```

I would advise you to use `String.Format()` on your FilterExpression. It lets you avoid syntax errors:

```
SqlDataSource.FilterExpression = String.Format("ModelName='{0}'", TextBox.Text);
```